How to refer to this nose trait?
Is there a term to refer to a ridge that runs across the bridge of the nose that some people have?
E.g:


Ideally it should be a more simple word rather than an anatomical term
Example sentences: "His nose had a _______" or "The bridge of his nose was _______"

A profile or three-quarter view might be more identifiable. Here are some nose shapes.

From The Dental Cosmos (1874) - A pronounced bridge is common among the white race , while a depressed bridge is the rule among Asiatic people. The negro is remarkable for the depressed bridge, and enormous expanse of tip and wings. But I don't know if what you're talking about is a pug nose.

This is known as having a wide nasal dorsum. Hete's a before-and-after photo of someone's nasal dorsum getting narrowed:

My source is this plastic surgery website; before you click on that link, note that it contains some rather gruesome anatomical images.
(You mention wanting a "simple word" for this, but of course if such a widely-known word existed then one would hardly need to ask about it here.)

OP could have found this but specifically wanted a non-anatomical term.

If OP found it they would have said in the question, per site rules. I think we can discount that.
